# Losing spaces when parsing XML with HTML tags to CSV

Tags: c#, html, xml, csv

I got a problem when I parse XML file which using HTML tags to CSV.

When I want to parse from:

```
"<strong>Nokia</strong> connecting people"
```

from XML description field using `< strong >` tags, in CSV it's

```
"<strong>Nokia</strong>connecting people".
```

Space between Nokia in tags and next word (connecting) is gone.

XML:

```
<Descritpion>
    <![CDATA[<p>
          <strong>Nokia</strong> connecting people
    </p>]]>
</Descritpion>
```

CSV:

```
<p>
    <strong>Nokia</strong>connecting people
</p>
```

C#:

```
else if (reader.Name == "Description")
{
    while (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement)
    {
        reader.Read();

        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.CDATA)
            desctiption= reader.Value;
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: When posting questions like this, it is better to give a complete example that someone could paste into an IDE, that way you will get help quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following code, I get the correct output, so maybe it is something with how you are outputting the value to CSV.  Note, I had to fix the spelling of Description in a few places, so maybe that is the cause of some of your problems:

```
var XML =
    "<Doc><Description><![CDATA[<p><strong>Nokia</strong> connecting people</p>]]></Description></Doc>";
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(XML));

string description ="";


while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.Name == "Description")
    {
        while (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement)
        {
            reader.Read();
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.CDATA)
                description = reader.Value;
        }
    }
}


Console.Write(description);
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer,
I've got bad line endings in XML, my VS fixed it when i restarted it ;)
Problem fixed!